# Вычисление косинуса посредством ряда Тейлора

Tags: c#

Ребята, здравствуйте. Имею проблему с вычислением значения косинуса с помощью ряда Тейлора. Стоит задача помимо вычисления значения косинуса сбрасывать вычисление цикла при значении очередного члена ряда ниже некоторого порогового значения, которое задается пользователем. Ниже мой код. При отсутствии сброса break, необходимого для прерывания цикла при учета порога пользователя все считается на ура. скажите, пжл, почему так и что придумать, чтобы программа работала?

```
   using System;
   class MainClass {
   public static void Main (string[] args) {
   Console.WriteLine("введите x");
   double x= double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
   Console.WriteLine("введите q");
   double q=double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());//значение порога, ниже которого останавливаем 
   вычисления
   double rad = (Math.PI/180 * x);
   double sum = 1;
   double num = 0;//начальное значение вычисленных членов ряда

   for (double n=1; n<=100; n++) {
  
   double member=(double)(Math.Pow(-1,n)*Math.Pow(rad, 2*n)/Factorial(2*n));
   if (member < q) {
   break;// сброс счетчика
   }
  
   sum+=member; // счетчик суммы вычислений
   num+=1;// счетчик суммы количества членов ряда
   
   }
   Console.WriteLine(sum);
   Console.WriteLine(num);
  
   }
   static double Factorial(double n) {
   double fact = 1;
   for (double i=1; i<=n; i++) {
   fact *=i;
   }
   return fact;`введите сюда код`
   }

   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> скажите, пжл, почему так

Потому что знак членов ряда меняется.

```
if (Math.Abs(member) < q)
  break;
```

Comment: спасибо тебе мил человек, что не побрезговал прочитать мою писанину. 95% пройдут мимо, 3% напишут свой код и только 2% таких как ты укажут на ошибку в собственном коде.

Comment: не в собственном, а в коде автора темы. прошу прощения.

Comment: @АртемБондаренко Пожалуйста. Успехов!